# Is taking the absolute value bars valid when obtaining the solution to this simple ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the separable ODE:
$$x'= \frac {1+x}{1-t^2}, x(0)=1$$

Via partial fractions and simple integration I got: $$x=2\sqrt{\left |\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right|}-1$$

[While solving it with Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3D%281%2Bx%29%2F%281-t%5E2%29%2C%20x%280%29%3D1) returns a bit of a different answer:
$$x = 2\sqrt {\frac{t+1}{1-t}}-1$$

Is Wolfram's answer as valid?

Comment: Your original equation is undefined if $t= \pm 1$.  Did you intend to solve for $t \in (-1,1)$ or for $t$ in some other range?

Comment: Also, do you intend for $x$ to be a function of $t$ or for $t$ to be a parameter for an autonomous differential equation?

Comment: $x$ is a function of $t$. Hmm I'm not sure, the question asked to find the maximal interval of existence of  solution, does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation blows up at $-1$ and $1$. Your interval of definition has to contain $0$ because that's where your initial condition is. So you will solve on $(-1,1)$. There, $\frac{t+1}{t-1}$ is always negative, and its absolute value is $\frac{t+1}{1-t}$.